# Modular menu and vector instantiation

Tags: c++, class, vector, menu

I would like to create a modular menu system.
This is based on a contatiner class Menu and menu entries objects provided by MenuItem class.

So my classes look like this:

```
class Menu
{
    public:
        void addItem(MenuItem* item);
        void removeItem(unsigned int _index);
        void clear();
        MenuItem* getCurrentItem();
        void invoke();
        void display();

    private:
        vector<MenuItem*> menu_items;
        unsigned int m_current_item;
};

class MenuItem
{
    public:
        explicit MenuItem(string data);
        void onSelect();
        void invokeCallback();
        string getData() const;

    private:
        string m_data;
};
```

Now i can create multiple instances of Menu for my menus (or sub-menus).

I can cast for example:

```
Menu home_menu;
Menu sub_menu;
```

Create MenuItems:

```
MenuItem First("First");           //home_menu item 1
MenuItem Second("Second");         //home_menu item 2
MenuItem First_sub("First sub");   //sub_menu item 1
```

And add them to the Menu (inside menu_items vector)

```
home_menu.addItem(&First);
home_menu.addItem(&Second);
sub_menu.addItem(&First_sub);
```

If I iterate the menu_items vector I can see all MenuItems objects (both home_menu and sub_menu).

I would like it to store only pointers to its relative menu, something like the vector menu_items is instantiated.

So the output when I cast: `home_menu.display()` should be: First Second
and when I cast: `sub_menu.display()`: First_sub

Could it be done ? What am I not considering in my implementation ?

Comment: Feels like the `MenuItem` should have it's own display method and know its parent so can report "First_sub" - the menu itself doesn't know this, and since it has the display method and nothing else does I suspect you're a bit stuck

Comment: Maybe I could end each menu with a null pointer so I could iterate untill I reach NULL. But then I should add each MenuItem for a menu one after the other without changing Menu assignment. What do you think ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want your Menu to take ownership of the MenuItems, you have to allocate them on the heap like so:

```
Menu home_menu;
Menu sub_menu;

{
    MenuItem* First = new MenuItem("First");           //home_menu item 1
    MenuItem* Second = new MenuItem("Second");         //home_menu item 2
    MenuItem* First_Sub = new MenuItem("First sub");   //sub_menu item 1

    home_menu.addItem(First);
    home_menu.addItem(Second);
    sub_menu.addItem(First_sub);
}
```

But your application will leak memory this way. Every object, that is created with `new`, must be deleted with `delete`

So you want to add a destructor to your class:

```
~Menu() {
    for(MenuItem* item : menu_items) {
        delete item;
    }
}
```

Comment: It would only solve the problem, thatPodarce only want to store the Menu pointer and not the MenuEntries on the stack. I dont unterstand the problem with the display method.

Comment: @OutOfBound You are right, twice. First yes, I only want to store pointers, second I made a mistake in my local code that I automatically corrected in my posted code. Basically I copy-pasted the same code without changing home_menu to sub_menu AddItem method. I paniced, I have to apologize. I've spent several hours on this problem searching for every possible issue on the internet and my problem was a copy-paste. I'm very sorry for this. Thanks to everyone who helped me.

Comment: If your question is solved, feel free to accept the answer, so other can see it is closed.